# Messaging in Lan

Tags: python, networking

I need advice on some problem I've been having.

The situation is like this. I have two devices in Local Network that are not directly connected with each other. Basically they don't know of each other existence. The problem is that I want one device to send message to the other device.

So the plan i have is this.

Make script that scans every ip address in local network and save output in txt file. Then send message to every ip address that is present in that file. On the other device make script that listens for upcoming messages(problem there is that i don't know where to listen, to whitch ip address to listen). Then that python script would send that to websocket so that js app can easily pick every message that has been sent.

This is my first app that includes some networking problems and message queues, so if any of you have some advice for me, or would do something different i would be very greatful if you can answer :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find communication peers on the network you might want to have a look at [udp broadcasts](https://www.google.com/#q=python+udp+broadcast).